# Hibernate: Delete the join entries but not the entities

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I have a ManyToMany relationship between employees and status groups, realized via a join table employee_status_group. I want to reach the following:

- when a status group gets deleted: delete the join entries but NOT the employee
- when an employee gets deleted: delete the join entries but NOT the group

Currently, I get the following exception when I try to delete all status groups:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
ERROR: update or delete on table "status_group" violates foreign key constraint "status_group_fk" on table "employee_status_group"
```

My code:

Employee.kt

```
@Entity
data class Employee(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    val id: UUID? = null,

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "employee_status_group",
               joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")],
               inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "status_group_id")])
    var statusGroups: MutableSet<StatusGroup> = mutableSetOf()
)
```

StatusGroup.kt

```
@Entity
data class StatusGroup(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    val id: UUID? = null
)
```

How do I have to set the cascade types to reach this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: there is *no* cascade type which does what you want.

You will have to remove the group from `Employee.statusGroups` yourself, before deleting the group.